# NoReverseMatch at / caused by regex?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I get the following error when running django server:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$v$']
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.8.6
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$v$']
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 495
```

My url in generic app is:

```
url(r'^v$', views.about, name ='about'),
url(r'^$', views.main_view, name= 'main_view'),
```

However, when I change the 'about' url to empty :

```
url(r'^$', views.about, name ='about'),
```

About view is used and the page loads ok. I don't understand how regex is crashing entire app. The goal was to have /v/ url in html template, like this:

```
 <li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'generic:about' %}>About page</a></li>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What is in your main project urls.py?

Comment: The only url linnking to generic app is this one: 
<pre>    url(r'^$', include('generic.urls', namespace='generic', app_name='generic')),<code>

In other words I would like to have www.example.com/v/, perhaps that's not what I stated in my URL files

Answer (score 0):

You have a $ at the end of your including pattern, so none of the included patterns will ever match. Remove it.

```
  url(r'', include('generic.urls', namespace='generic', app_name='generic')),
```

Comment: Indeed, this solves the problem. Thank you for your time to answer this question!